# Randomly Selecting Pixels in a Picture Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a grayscale picture that I would like to manually add noise to. First I would like to randomly select a pixel , generate a random values from 0 to 1, multiple the value by 255 and replace the pixel's previous value with the newly gotten number, and repeat the process 100 times.

I believe i have most of the code down

```
    clc;
fid = fopen(str);
myimage = fread(fid, [512 683]);
fclose(fid);


for i = 1:100
A(i) = rand(1) * 255;
end
```

I just cannot figure out how to randomly select 100 pixels from the image and how to replace them with the values I have created. assistance would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the index of 100 random pixels:

```
rPix = floor(rand(1,100) * numel(myimage)) + 1;
rVal = rand(1,100);
myimage(rPix) = 255 * rVal;
```

**explanation**

```
rand(1,100)  : an array of 1 x 100 random numbers
numel(myimage) : number of pixels
product of the two : a random number between 0 and n
floor() : the next smallest integer. This "almost" points to 100 random pixels; we're off by 1, so
+ 1 : we add one to get a valid index.
```

We now have a valid random index. Note that in Matlab it's valid to use 1D indexing into a 2D array, as long as you don't use a number larger than the number of elements in the array. Thus if

```
A = rand(3,3);
b = A(5);
```

is the same as

```
b = A(2,2); % because the order is A(1,1), A(2,1), A(3,1), A(1,2), A(2,2), ...
```

The next line:

```
rVal = rand(1, 100);
```

Generates 100 random numbers (between 0 and 1). The final line

```
myimage(rPix) = 255 * rVal;
```

Indexes (randomly) 100 elements from `myimage`, and assigns the values from `rVal` multiplied by 255. This is a very powerful part of Matlab: *vectorization*. You can have (and, for speed, should always try to have) Matlab operate on many numbers in a single operation. The above is equivalent to

```
for ii = 1:100
  myimage(rPix(ii)) = 255 * rVal(ii);
end
```

Only much faster...

Comment: an explanation would be great, its working perfectly, but i would like to know what exactly i just did.

Answer (score 1):

To get the **random pixel**, you can take two variables **x** and **y** and generate random values for each of them inside the limits. Generate the random pixel value and replace the value at (x,y) with the random value you got. It would look like:

```
for i=1:100
  x = randi([1 512]);
  y = randi([1 683]);
  myimage(x,y) = rand(1)*255;
end;
```

Comment: Well, randi is a matlab function. You don't need to include any sort of toolbox. I am running matlab 2012a and it has randi in it. You can check by running **help randi** in your matlab.

Comment: OK - I am running an older version. I stand corrected - your modified code will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `randperm`:

```
image = imread('image_name.extension');
[row col] = size(image);
indices = randperm(row*col);
loc = randperm(100);

randomly_selected_pixels = image(indices(loc));

% Assign the values that you have to these "randomly_selected_pixels"
```