# How to find K random different pixels in an image?

Tags: matlab

I know how to find a random pixel by using rand function, for both x&y in the limits of the image. Then do it K times with a loop.

However I'd like to do it in smarter way and make sure I don't pick the same 
(x, y) coordinate. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at the answers to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17177230/randomly-selecting-pixels-in-a-picture-matlab) question.

Answer (score 6):

Use [`randperm`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) (no toolbox required):

```
K = 10;
[h, w, c] = size(image);
[X, Y] = ind2sub([h w], randperm(h*w, K));
```

Comment: That will work too! I had forgotten you could tell `randperm` how many elements to return!

Answer (score 4):

The tricky part here is avoiding repetition. If you have the Statistics Toolbox you can use [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/randsample.html):

```
k = 10;
[m,n] = size(image(:,:,1));    %// works with 3- and 1-channel images
s = randsample(m*n, k);        %// get k random indices
[X, Y] = ind2sub([m, n], s);   %// convert indices to x,y coordinates
```

On my test run with a 512x512x3 image I got the following coordinates:

```
X =    
   464   143   174   235   437   201   348   272   212   260

Y =
   499   449   508   148   107   114   341   196    60   224
```

Answer (score 2):

`randi` generates integers between 1 and a specified limit, you can use that with your image size to generate pixel coordinates. To make sure you don't pick the same coordinates again maintain a matrix of logicals and mark pixels you are picking.
If you just want to pick K random pixels from the image I would suggest use something like `randi(imgSize,K,2)` to generate a matrix of indices. You could end up with duplicates in the matrix and to eliminate those you can use `unique` with the `'rows'` argument.

Comment: Seems like an appropriate username for this question!