# Sampling technique for creating point in 2D Plane with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, sampling

I want to write a code in which when it runs, It create 30 point in the 2D Plane.
and every time when the code runs, the points have different coordinates.

I try using hammersly sampling. But the problem of this sampling technique is the points have the same coordinates.

Comment: Can't you use a simple [`rand`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html) function? ex. `rand(30, 2)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find K random different pixels in an image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34403738/how-to-find-k-random-different-pixels-in-an-image)