# Select and fill random pixels in jpg

Tags: r

Let's say I have a `.jpg` such as below. Is it possible in `R` to select say 25% of pixels then produce a a new `.jpg` with those pixels filled in a given colour. Similar to the following question in matlab [Randomly Selecting Pixels in a Picture Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17177230/randomly-selecting-pixels-in-a-picture-matlab)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way

```
img = jpeg::readJPEG(system.file("img", "Rlogo.jpg", package="jpeg"))    

Npixels = prod(dim(img)[1:2])
Rpixels = sample(Npixels, 0.25 * Npixels) # randomly select 25% of the pixels
img[,,1][Rpixels] = 1 # set the red layer to one in selected pixels
img[,,2][Rpixels] = 0 # set blue and green to zero
img[,,3][Rpixels] = 0
```

Now we can plot the modified image to see how it looks

```
par(mai=c(0,0,0,0))
plot.new()
rasterImage(img,   0, 0, 1, 1)
```

[image]

To export as a new jpeg file we can do

```
jpeg::writeJPEG(img, "test.jpeg")
```